# R: X13 arima (seasonal::seas) error

Tags: r, time-series

I get the following error every other time when I run the `seasonal::seas` function (I keep `a` unchanged). :

```
> a <- ts(rnorm(100), start = 2000, frequency = 12)
> seas(a)
Error in x[[2]] : subscript out of bounds
> seas(a)

Call:
seas(x = a)

Coefficients:
     Leap Year         Weekday        Constant  MA-Seasonal-12  
     -0.533421        0.069256       -0.006748        0.723464
```

With my own time series the error happens in most cases and is less regular. Now, I have located the error. It is in the following line

```
file.suffix <- unlist(lapply(strsplit(flist, "\\."), function(x) x[[2]]))
```

But according to my debugger, `flist`is

```
Browse[3]> flist
```

> [1] "data.dta"          "fort.6"            "iofile.err"      "iofile.est"        "iofile.lks"        "iofile.log"
>   [7] "iofile.mdl"        "iofile.out"        "iofile.rsd"       "iofile.s10"        "iofile.s11"        "iofile.s12"
>   [13] "iofile.s13"        "iofile.s16"        "iofile.s18"        "iofile.spc"        "iofile.udg"        "iofile_Profiler.t"

but in often the ".t" is missing from the last string.

How can I proceed. One Idea I had was to change the code in the package to add the ".t" to the string if it was missing, but I don't really want to mess with it (and I don't know how to). Another idea I had was to create a loop that would repeat the function call until it works. Any ideas?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error. It works on my machine....Win7 64bit, R 3.2.4, seasonal 1.2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3 Months Late

I was able to reproduce this issue. It occurs when using `x13as.exe` instead of `x13ashtml.exe`. The `x13as.exe` binary produces this `iofile_Profiler` file. (the `iofile` prefix is defined by seasonal::seas not x13as.)

The quickest solution is to place the `x13ashtml` binary in the `Sys.getenv("X13_PATH")` location.

https://www.census.gov/srd/www/x13as/